# Split email address by username and email domain

Tags: google-sheets, regex-replace

I would like to split the username and email domain from an email address.
For Example, test.leo@gmail.com to **test.leo** and **gmail ** without .com

`Formula used: =IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(Filter!$A:$AY,MATCH($A39,Filter!$A:$A,0),MATCH(N$1,Filter!$1:$1,0)), "\[a-zA-Z0-9_]",""), "@"), "")`

Answer (score 1):

tested on couple of email address varieties here. you may test it out extensively on your whole data set & see how it goes...

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A2:A),REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^(.*)@(.*)\."),"\.co$",""),))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: I think it won't work on cases like martin.contreras@gmail.com, am I right?

Comment: its testing good for that specific email @Martín

Comment: You're right, I thought it would work on both members separately 

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with this option:

=INDEX(IF(ISEMAIL(A2:A),REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(.+)@(.+?)."),))

[image]

If you need only to remove the last ".***" Just remove the interrogation mark